# Securing an msi to prevent unauthorized use

Tags: installation

Im having trouble coming up with a way to secure an installer for an app ive made. I dont need anything too intense, just something to 'lock' the installer I guess.

Thanks.

Due to the first comment, when I say secure I mean using a password or key to prevent unauthorized use.

Comment: I don't understand in what way you want to lock the installer. Lock it for what? When should it be locked? When should it be unlocked? Please explain the question better.

Comment: I edited it. I wasnt very clear. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnS It's still not clear. Do you want a kind of license key so that without the key your app does not work?

Comment: Well, I do know conceptually about that method but I dont know how to implement it or what other options there are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to unpack the files contained in a .msi without running the installer by using 3rd party tools. If you want to prevent this you would have to decrypt the files with a [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It is probably better to put any kind of serial validation in the app itself so people can not copy a working install...

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for this:

1. Serial number validation during install. Most setup tools offer support for it and it's pretty easy to configure.
2. Application trial/registration. This is a more complex feature and only a couple of setup tools support it.

Each approach has it's own implementation and advantages, so you should first decide what you want. After that, you can try to implement it in your installer. You can then ask for more specific questions when encountering problems.

Here is a list of setup tools which can get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software