# How to prevent unauthorized MSI installation?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, authorization

I have two versions of the same MSI package: 'genuine' and 'developer'. The former is intended for shipping, whereas the latter is built on developers' computers for the sake of testing, etc. I want to prevent accidental leaking of the 'developer' version, so that the end user couldn't have it installed. What are the possible approaches?

The MSI is built with WiX, just in case.

I've seen [Securing an msi to prevent unauthorized use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352693/securing-an-msi-to-prevent-unauthorized-use), but the answers there are focused on preventing launch not installation. I don't need to obfuscate, encrypt or protect the package contents. I only need to protect unqualified users from accindentally screwing things on their machines, due to erroneous packages being installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, because MSI is an open book  ( Edit with ORCA ), it's best to do this type of enforcement (DRM) in the application at runtime.  I could suggest all sorts of techniques in the MSI but they could be removed by someone knowing what they are doing.

What is your "leaking" concern?  Do you not trust your developers?  Do you not trust your CM / Release practices?   Do you have a strong NDA in place?  Proper IT security?

Comment: I only concerned with improper packages accidentally reaching users due to lack of company's process discipline. (Yes, I try to correct it as well, but it's going to take some time..)

Comment: @christopher Painter: Just out of curiosity, what are some techniques that you think would help to obfuscate a MSI package?

Comment: I've updated the question to state the intent more clearly, and yes, all sorts of techniques are welcome, simpliest first =)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying only to prevent accidental misuse - that is, someone unknowingly installing a developer copy who wanted a user copy - I would suggest a simple launch condition. You would document that "developers" must put something on their machine (perhaps a file, a registry key, or even an environment variable), and have the msi check for that. It would then refuse to install unless the "I am a developer" footprint was there.

If you want to avoid the footprint, you could require that "developers" launch the msi from the command line and pass `DEVELOPER=1` and instead check for the property. Or more extreme you could require specific and changing values for the `DEVELOPER` property. It all depends on how annoying you want to make it to be a "developer" for your product.

Note that this is not secure in the slightest against malicious misuse. Among other limitations, it does nothing to prevent administrative installations that allow access to all the files.

Note as well that it's still a smart idea to follow the usual launch condition patterns to avoid preventing uninstallation of the package.